# Expansion of function around point using $\log(x+1) = x - x^2/2+...$

Tags: taylor-expansion

In *Chaos and Fractals, New Frontiers of Science, 1st Ed.*, a function is expanded around a point:

[image]

**I know how to get the result, but not by using the logarithm approximation. How should I use it here?**

Note: The original text actually says $\log(x)=x-x^2/2$, but I assumed it's a typo.

Comment: I think it’s a typo., and note the approximation is for $log_e$

Comment: Yeah, I noticed, and understand it will lead to the $1/ln2$ factor, but I still can't get how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a Taylor second order expansion about the appropriate point:

Let $\phi(t) = t \log t + (1-t) \log(1-t)$.

Then Taylor gives $\phi(t) \approx \phi({1 \over 2}) + \phi'({1 \over 2})(t-{1 \over 2}) + {1 \over 2}\phi''({1 \over 2})(t-{1 \over 2})^2$, or explicitly
$\phi(t) \approx - \log 2 + 2 (t-{1 \over 2})^2$
(about  $t={1 \over 2}$).

(Note that $\phi'({1 \over 2}) = 0$ since $\phi$ is 'even' about $t={1 \over 2}$.)

Since $f(\alpha) = -{1 \over \log 2}\phi({\alpha_\max - \alpha \over \alpha_\max - \alpha_\min})$, you get
$ f(\alpha) \approx 1 -{2 \over \log 2} ({\alpha_0-\alpha \over \alpha_\max - \alpha_\min } )^2$.

**Note**: The appropriate expansion of $\log$ would be
$\log t \approx - \log 2 + 2 (t-{1 \over 2}) -2 (t-{1 \over 2})^2$,
however it is far easier to work in terms of $\phi$ above as it 'handles' the
necessary cancellations.

Comment: This is neat, thanks! I'm still not convinced this is their approach, but it's the closest I have that doesn't waste much time with calculations, and apparently it was obvious to you, so I'll take it.

Comment: I don't know where the original text expansion came from, if one expands $\log$ around ${1 \over 2}$ and simplifies, then one gets $\log x \approx -\log 2 - {3 \over 2} +4x -2 x^2$.

Comment: Using the version I wrote of the approximation, I guess we could use it by writing $\log(x+\frac{1}{2})$ as $\log(\frac{1}{2}(2x+1))$ (to still expand in $x=0$) and by writing $f(\alpha)$ in terms of $\alpha-\alpha_0=x$. It's still far-fetched, but it works.